# Processing json string in mql5

Tags: mql5, metatrader5

I have received the following string:

```
{'1.128330': {'sell': {'id': '1', 'got': 93.03059560034244}, 'buying': {'id': '2', 'got': 80.29916788508336}}, '1.128520': {'sell': {'id': '1', 'got': 16.857589570319895}, 'buying': {'id': '2', 'got': 225.53801097382126}}, '1.128480': {'sell': {'id': '1', 'got': 25.107832004252355}, 'buying': {'id': '2', 'got': 173.6565182150294}}, '1.128600': {'sell': {'id': '1', 'got': 5.970539130416359}, 'buying': {'id': '2', 'got': 361.9910279494408}}, '1.128640': {'sell': {'id': '1', 'got': 2.5341625886266863}, 'buying': {'id': '2', 'got': 393.3836268867237}}, '1.128020': {'sell': {'id': '1', 'got': 428.3577531480875}, 'buying': {'id': '2', 'got': None}}}
```

I am not understanding how I can process and separate the values of the json in mql5, as no library is efficient enough to help.
I am willing to get the output as:

```
price[] = {1.128330,1.128520,1.128480,1.128600,1.128640,1.128020}
whatdo[] = {1,2,1,2,1,2,1,2,1,2,1,2}
gain[] = {93.03059560034244,80.29916788508336,16.857589570319895,225.53801097382126,25.107832004252355,173.6565182150294,5.970539130416359,361.9910279494408,2.5341625886266863,393.3836268867237,428.3577531480875,0}
```

Please let me know what I can do.

Answer (score 1):

You may use as much 'native' as it could be possible solution. [This](https://www.mql5.com/en/code/13663) one should be good for you but keep in mind that it does not handle json-arrays, you should loop over the array elements. Here is a link with an [example](https://www.mql5.com/ru/forum/63015/page9#comment_6618109)

If I were you I would code sth like that:

```
 #include <jason.mqh>
 string receivedJson="{'1.128330': {'sell': {'id': '1', 'got': 93.03059560034244}, 'buying': {'id': '2', 'got': 80.29916788508336}}, '1.128520': {'sell': {'id': '1', 'got': 16.857589570319895}, 'buying': {'id': '2', 'got': 225.53801097382126}}, '1.128480': {'sell': {'id': '1', 'got': 25.107832004252355}, 'buying': {'id': '2', 'got': 173.6565182150294}}, '1.128600': {'sell': {'id': '1', 'got': 5.970539130416359}, 'buying': {'id': '2', 'got': 361.9910279494408}}, '1.128640': {'sell': {'id': '1', 'got': 2.5341625886266863}, 'buying': {'id': '2', 'got': 393.3836268867237}}, '1.128020': {'sell': {'id': '1', 'got': 428.3577531480875}, 'buying': {'id': '2', 'got': None}}}"

 double price[], gain[]; int what2do[];
 if(!processJson(receivedJson))print("error");

 boolean processJson(string inputJson,double &price[],double &gain[],int what2do[])
   {
    CJAVAL json(NULL, jtUNDEF);
    if(!json.Deserialize(inputJson))
        return(false);
    if(ArrayResize(price,json.m_e)==-1 || ArrayResize(gain,json.m_e)==-1 || ArrayResize(what2do,json.m_e)==-1)
        return(false);
    const string sell="sell", buy="buy", got="got", none="None";
    for(int i=0;i<json.m_e;i++)
      {
       price[i]=(double)json.m_e[i].m_key.ToDouble();
       for(int int j=0;j<json.m_e[i].m_e;j++)
         {
          string cmd=(int)json.m_e[i].m_e[j];
          what2do[i]=(cmd==sell ? 2 : (cmd==buy ? 1 : 0) );
          string gain=json.m_e[i].m_e[j][got];
          gain[i]=gain==none ? INT_MIN : DoubleToString(gain);
         }
      }
    return(true);
   }
```

Comment: Thank you Daniel. Yes I have seen that it was not handling arrays. Hence, I thought of have certain solutions that resembles the json library what python has. It is simple to understand and I thought I would have something like that in MQL5. Some are difficult for me to understand. Thank you.

Comment: I also need to use jason.mqh library, can anyone help me, see details of what i need help with here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60801625/processing-json-string-in-mql4