# Processing json string in mql4

Tags: mql4, metatrader4, mql5

I have received the following string:

```
{"records":[{"id":"rec4haaOncoQniu8U","fields":{"orders1":5},"createdTime":"2020-02-08T09:08:22.000Z"}]}
```

I am not understanding how I can process and separate the values of the json in mql4 using the "JAson.mqh " library, located here: https://www.mql5.com/en/code/13663

I need the values of "orders" located under "fields" , **value = 5**.
the only "KEYS" that changes are the keys within the "fields" values.

i would like to be able to get the values with something like this:

```
string value1 = Result[0].["fields"].["orders1"]; //5
string value2 = Result[0].["fields"].["orders2"];
```

Please let me know what I can do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get the value using the following format. Note that it has to be casted to a type. (I have casted it to `int` as it is the type it is in the `JSON`, but you can cast it to `string` as well)

`int value1 = json["records"][0]["fields"]["orders1"].ToInt(); // if you want to make it a string use ToStr() instead of ToInt()`

Here is a full example of what I did

```
string jsonString = "{\"records\": [{\"id\": \"rec4haaOncoQniu8U\",\"fields\": {\"orders1\": 5 }\"createdTime\": \"2020-02-08T09:08:22.000Z\"}]}";

if(json.Deserialize(jsonString))
   Alert(json["records"][0]["fields"]["orders1"].ToInt());
```

Hope it helped.

Comment: Thanks, it worked. Maybe you can help with another issue, see here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61068665/mql4-set-trailing-step-according-to-order-swap-and-minimum-stop-allowed